# WinForm control to list files in a directory

Tags: .net, winforms

I'm new to the WinForms control toolbox, so I'm looking to get suggestions on which control I should use for the following simple situation:

I want to have an area on my form that shows a list of the files in a particular directory.

My first quick and dirty inclination is to put a textbox on the form and populate it line-by-line using Directory.GetFiles() - but I know there has to be a more appropriate control.  Maybe gridview?

(.NET 3.5)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325464/listing-files-with-checkboxes-c-winforms

Comment: Thanks Jon but that question's requirements included a check box, which I would think rules out some potential answers to my more generalized need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ListView would be the preferred control.  That way you can click on each file name individually, for highlighting/copying, etc

You would also be able to have multiple columns in detail view, and set up sorting on file size, date created, type, etc.

Another advantage of ListView is that you can select multiple items.  I use this to delete or open a group of files instead of just one at a time, very handy.